# Symfony2 Unable to generate url in error page

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

Since I upgraded to Symfony 2.7, I get an `error 500` on my error pages when I try to generate a route in twig:

```
<!-- app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.ywig -->
<a href="{{ path( 'homepage' ) }}">Take me home</a>
```

The error is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "homepage" as such route does not exist.") in TwigBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig at line 47.

I can call the route from any page that is not located within the `app` folder. The route exists in `src\Acme\AcmeBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml`.

Edit:

My routing:

```
homepage:
   path:     /
   defaults: { _controller: SiteBundle:Site:index }
```

Comment: what about `<a href="/homepage">Take me home</a>`

Comment: It works but I give up on Symfony's powerful routing module.

Comment: whats that??  i didnt get you

Comment: May we have a look to your routing.yml?

Comment: @scoolnico It's up, but it is very basic. Anyway the route works in other twig files (those not in the app folder I think).

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache?

Comment: Both manually and with the command line. But it looks like I have a cache clearing/building issue recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the `Lunetics` bundle for locale was resetting the locale in sub-requests. I disabled it and everything is fine.

Comment: For me I needed to change the locale in parameters.yml from en to a locale I was actually using : es or fr